# Play Framework Separating UI web app and REST api

Tags: playframework

I am developing Play project which serves the web interface and REST API's for mobile devices, now i want to host REST API's in separate instance (i.e api.example.com) and web app in (example.com) separate instance, also REST API's should not be accessible in web app, same as, should not show the web app in REST API instance. Is there way to anything can i do with Nginx routing or will it be best to keep 2 separate play project, one for REST api and another on for web?

Comment: Is this a Nginx or a Play Framework question?

Comment: @Nick Play framework question, Is there any possibility to do it Nginx?

Comment: I think it is an architecture question. What are your concerns? You don't want to have two projects? Are you worrying about how to share code between the two projects? Or you want to know how to configure nginx to handle such use case?

Comment: Yes, its architecture question, I can keep two projects, I am going to share the code between two project is Sbt project, it acts like library and can be accessible with both projects. But i have doubt that, Is it the right way? Or What is best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would suggest you make two separate applications, one for the API and one for the front-end. Depending on you requirements, the front-end could possibly even be completely static (HTML, JS etc.).

If you want to have only one Play app, which has all the code for both the API and the front-end, and let's say the Play app serves your front-end on route `/` and the API under `/api`, you could try the following Nginx config:

```
upstream playapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000; # replace with your Play app's IP and port
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://playapp;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api {
        deny  all;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://playapp/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I've not tested this, but it should come close.